# I'm getting undefined packages even though I have them in my package.json and node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, nestjs

So I'm developing a web app using NestJS as its backend. Also I'm using docker to build all my backend. I'm having a problem that some installed packages logs as "undefined" and some other works properly.

For example in my CreateUser class I have

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Injectable()
export class CreateUser {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepo: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async execute(input: CreateUserInput): Promise<User> {
    console.log('bcrypt', bcrypt);
    const user = this.usersRepo.create(input);
    user.email = input.email.trim().toLowerCase();
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(input.password, 10);
    const newUser = await this.usersRepo.save(user);
    return newUser;
  }
```

When I execute this function it logs this

```
bcrypt undefined
data TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
```

But if I go to my node_modules I have the bcrypt module installed. And the same happens in my package.json

I think its a docker problem but I've gone into the container and inspected the node_modules folder and it also is installed in there. Here goes my docker file just in case

```
FROM node:12-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV development

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Any ideas of why im not being able to use this package?

Comment: There's a somewhat common pattern of Node containers ignoring everything in the Dockerfile, bind-mounting a host directory over the application code, and then mounting an anonymous volume over `node_modules`.  This pattern ignores changes to `package.json` and could lead to the problem you're seeing.  Are you running the container with volume mounts like this, and if so, does deleting them help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do like this

```
import {hash} from 'bcrypt'
```

and then

```
 user.password = await hash(input.password, 10);
```

to understand more please refer to :https://learnjsx.com/category/2/posts/es6-javaScript

Comment: Thats another way of doing the same thing im trying to do, the thing is that it logs "undefined", looks like it cant find the package

Comment: you can then do `console.log('bcrypt', hash);`

Comment: the package exports functions and not the whole object, so you need to import each function and use it, the syntax that you are using above works only if the exported object contains functions inside which is not the case for the bcrypt package

Comment: @JuanPedroPontVergés No it's not the same thing. It would be the same only if you did `import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'`, but you don't have the `* as `, so _your_ version is instead equivalent to `import {default as bcrypt} from 'bcrypt'`. Also, if the package weren't found, then `bcrypt.hash` wouldn't be undefined (what is `bcrypt` then?) but the `import` statement itself would fail.